Error when changing font size in ggplot theme for specific fonts?
I am trying to create a custom theme with ggplot for plotting and have run into an issue where a few font sizes throw an error when changed. When trying to use the Calibri font, size 9, 10, and 12 result in the following error:
Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
  polygon edge not found (zero-width or zero-height?)

This is not an issue when I use smaller or larger sizes, nor with some other font families.
Here is an example which results in this error. Changing to another family (i.e. family = "Times New Roman") or adjusting the font size works just fine.
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
data <- iris

ggplot(data, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "len",
       y = "wid",
       title = "iris") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Calibri", size = 11))

# size = 9/10/12 throw error

Any help would is appreciated.
Edit: This appears to be an issue with the AGG backend for RStudio Graphics. Switching to the default fixes the error, but results in the graphics rendering slightly different.

I cannot reproduce the error. The plots render fine with Calibri 9, 10, 11, and 12. Perhaps something on your system? Have you tried restarting R, or the machine?

I did try restarting. It seems that the issue is arising from using the AGG backend in the RStudio Graphics options (updating ragg did not fix this - my mistake).
